# Clamp Meter is not working

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, multimeter

[image: Image with broken digits and battery sign]when selecting continuity test, starts continuous beeping sound even with test leads removed. Also there is battery sign on display and no zero when it turns on. 
I used it to check voltage of mosquito racket. It was beyond given rang since then its not working.
I checked circuit if it is burn some where but I did not found any thing specious.

Comment: so would that mean change the battery in this meter?

Comment: I changed battery once. I wasn't work anymore, right now it is not getting on.

Comment: VTC - This question about the use or repair of an electronic device is off topic here.

Comment: Get a new one, they are cheap

Answer (score 2):

> I used it to check voltage of mosquito racket

It might be just the battery that needs changing (BAT sign on display) or the several thousand volts on a mosquito racket zapper has zapped your meter. Note that your meter is only rated up to 1000 volts DC.

[This Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-killing_device) quotes this: -

> The grid of the flyswatter is electrically charged to a voltage of
>   between 500 and 1500 volts (V)

[This Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_zapper) quotes this about AC powered zappers: -

> A high-voltage power supply powered by mains electricity, which may be
>   a simple transformerless voltage multiplier circuit made with diodes
>   and capacitors, generates a voltage of 2,000 volts or more, high
>   enough to conduct through the body of an insect which bridges the two
>   grids, but not high enough to spark across the air gap.

Comment: yeah but now  how could i get it back in working???

Comment: I have no idea how to repair this device.

Comment: If you are wanting to know how to repair an electrical device like this you should try and locate fault finding guides and/or circuit diagrams. This site is not particularly suited for giving repair instructions, in fact it is against the rules. Guidelines: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic